# Drupal Generating nodes in a nightly cron Job

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views, drupal-theming

What should be the best of generating nodes from a CSV file in a nightly Cron Job? Is there any good module for doing this or better to programatically create content using node_save in hook_cron() function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the drupal [feeds module](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to achieve this. With feeds you can periodically import entities from a data source (eg. CSV or a RSS feed).

If the Node-processor of the feeds module does not fit your requirements, you should try to create a custom module as you already suggested.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already checked feeds module. But i saw some issues in the Issue queue mentioning that feeds module is not creating all nodes in the cron. sometimes it is struck in between and shows only 20% or 30% of the content is imported. So I am thinking of other best alternatives for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for the Feeds Module, I'm using it on many projects and didn't have any issues whatsoever. Just one thing to remember, if there is a lot of data which needs to be imported just make sure you check the "Process in background" checkbox on the individual importer settings page under the Basic Settings tab.